# Where is the Magento 1.x PHP 5.4 patch?

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, php-5.4

I'm trying to download the PHP 5.4 patch for Magento 1.x CE but I cannot find it, I think this guide is out of date:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/php5.4_patch.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download252 :)

Sorry for one line answer (have to write something)